# How to scroll to top an overflow div with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$('.lb').click(function() {
    $('#modal').hide();

    var id  = $(this).attr('id');
    var dir = '/lightbox/' + id + '.php';

    $('#lightbox').find('#modal').load(dir, function() {
        $('#modal').show();
        $('#lightbox').fadeIn(200);
    });
});
```

I currently have a dynamic lightbox but everytime I scroll it to the bottom then load a different page, it stays scrolled into the bottom of `#modal`

I've tried

```
$('#modal').show();
$('#modal').scrollTop(0);
$('#lightbox').fadeIn(200);
```

but it doesnt work

any help would be great!

EDIT - forgot to mention that im using http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/

Comment: are you sure the scrollbar is on the overflow div and not on the page? do you have a screenshot? live example?

Comment: yep, #modal has overflow:scroll... But i think its also worth mentioning that Im also using http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#div').scrollTop(0);
```

works fine

## [LIVE_DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UcXLW/13/)

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that Im using http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/. It should be causing my problem. Do you know how I can work around this?

Comment: There's gotta be something wrong with my messed up codes. I gave up and just went and deleted the contents before loading the new one to reset the scrollbars

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('#lightbox').find('#modal').load(dir, function() {
    $('#modal').show();
    $('#modal').scrollTop(0);
    // Do also
    $('#modal').scrollLeft(0);
    $('#lightbox').fadeIn(200);
});
```

Comment: No it doesnt, but I guess I should also mention that im using http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/ if that matters...

Comment: Yes that's the issue!

Comment: Look into it's API, there must be scroll event.